# Internal Stylesheet in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress, alt

i try a lot of time to put an alt atribute in and internal stylesheet page with wordpress. Using de virtual template image.
But when i put the alt attrribute in the internal stylesheet i can't see the property in the page.
I Use montezuma template.

```
<style>
    img {
      width:800px;
      height:533px;
      alt="Hola"
    }
</style>

<img src="hola.jpg">
```

Thanks!

Pd: Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alt attributes are meant to be put in HTML, not in the CSS.

```
<img src="shark.jpg" alt="shark" title="Image of an shark" />
```

Comment: Yes, you can't have alt attributes in css.